# R match rownames from different dataframe columns and replace with 1(if match) and 0(if no match)

Tags: r, matrix, replace, match

I have a question about matching columns and replace this with a 1 if there is a match and 0 if there is no match. I have a matrix with columnnames. I want to match ik with 3 other dataframe columns and replace in that matrix if it is a match or not.

Finally i want to create this matrix:

```
   dataframe1 dataframe2 dataframe3
aaa    1     0     0
aab    0     1     0
aac    1     0     0
aad    0     1     1
aae    1     1     1

dataframe1 <- c("aaa","aac","aae") 
dataframe2 <- c("aab","aad","aae") 
dataframe3 <- c("aad","aae")
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: dataframe1 <- c("aaa","aac","aae")  dataframe2 <- c("aab","aad","aae") dataframe3 <- c("aad","aae") If someone can produce a matrix out of this variables, I will be very happy!!

Comment: Good. Now put that into your question, and I might be tempted to have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df1 <- c("aaa","aac","aae")
df2 <- c("aab","aad","aae") 
df3 <- c("aad","aae", "x", "y")

dfs <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)

zz <- sapply(dfs, function(x)df3 %in% x)
rownames(zz) <- df3
zz
      df1   df2
aad FALSE  TRUE
aae  TRUE  TRUE
x   FALSE FALSE
y   FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: And to get the zeros and ones, do `zz <- sapply(dfs, function(x)1*(df3 %in% x))`